# How can I put XML in a HTML template? python/Django

Tags: python, html, xml, django

I want to put my variable user_serialized_xml in my HTML template, but I am not sure how can I do it :/

This is my views.py

```
> def user_xml(request):
>     context = {}
> 
>     user_serialized_xml = serializers.serialize("xml", Usuario.objects.all())
>     context['user_serialized_xml'] = user_serialized_xml
>     return render_to_response('profile_xml.html', context)
```

And this is my HTML template (yes, really short!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{{user_serialized_xml}}
```

It gives me this error: Could not parse the remainder: '{user_serialized_xml' from '{user_serialized_xml'

Thank you!

Comment: You only closed 2 curly brackets​ but opened 3.

Comment: Sorry, it was a fail on the post ! Edited :)

Comment: right now your code is correct, I have tested, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rendering in your template like this,

```
{{ user_serialized_xml | safe }}
```

It will avoid escaping HTML characters. For more information, see this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs)